# Is it possible to make the aws cloudformation code shorter than this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am writing aws cloudformation code. Could you possibly make it more concise than the code I wrote?

```
PublicSubnet:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
  Properties:
    VPCId: !Ref VPC
    CibrBlock: !Sub
    - ${CibrBlockHeader}
    - { CibrBlockHeader: If [ IsProd, !FindInMap [ VPC, CibrBlockHeader, CibrBlockFooter ], !FindInMap [ VPC, DevCibrBlockHeader, CibrBlockFooter ] ] }
```

Comment: Why? What's wrong with the current length?

Comment: I just want to make that `!If` statement more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should work (don't need `Sub`):

```
PublicSubnet:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
  Properties:
    VPCId: !Ref VPC
    CibrBlock: 
      CibrBlockHeader: If [ IsProd, !FindInMap [ VPC, CibrBlockHeader, CibrBlockFooter ], !FindInMap [ VPC, DevCibrBlockHeader, CibrBlockFooter ] ]
```